# when searching for a letter in a list, its gives me always two output or more. how do i fix this and what am i missing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
wordlist = ['a', 'b']
letters = ['l']

for item in wordlist:
    for character in letters:
        if character == item:
             print ("found")
             break
        else:
            if character != item:
                print ("not found")
```

It gives me:

```
not found
not found.
```

I just want 1 not found as an output and not 2.

I think the rest speaks for itself? if not please feel free to ask.

Comment: But you can only say "not found" at the **end of the loop**...

Comment: define some variable before the loop starts `found = False` then if you find the character set it to true `found = True`.  After the loop, you can have some `if found: print('found') else: print('not found')`

Comment: Do you want to print not found if at least one `item` in `wordlist` is not found, or only if all of them are not found?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. i defined some variables like you said and it helped me just fine. I now have a list that looks cooler :D. But it not solved my problem but it improved my coding so im good ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a flag that imply whether you entered to the found section, if no, you break from the outer loop:

```
wordlist = ['a', 'b']
letters = ['l',"a"]

for item in wordlist:
    found_flag = False
    for character in letters:
        if character == item:
             found_flag = True
             break

    if found_flag:
      print (item ,": found")
    else:
      print (item , ": not found")
      break
```

Comment: Thanks, a good way to write it differently. Makes it clearer what is found and what not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
i=0
for item in wordlist:
    if item not in letters:
        i+=1
if i > 0:
    print "Not found"
```

Comment: if i change the letter to "a" it still says not found in my shell. I changed nothing but maybe im doing something wrong with your code.

Comment: Can you check that the code you have copied and pasted is properly indented?

Answer (score -1):

Study your own code more carefully. Step through it yourself.

You are running the code for each item in wordlist. There are two of them and neither are matches, so it will print "not found" twice.

You don't need to write your own functions for this. There are many pre-written builtins to do simple things like this for you. Read the Python documentation about lists.

Comment: this would be better as a comment

Comment: Why? I answered the question.